# How to filter a key using jq in bash

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "a_key": "A",
  "key_to_filter": "B",
  "c_key": "C"
}
```

I want to get all the keys using `jq` as a compressed response (using `jq -c "keys"`).

How can I get all the keys of this JSON without the key "key_to_filter"?

In other words, I need ["a_key", "c_key"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just subtract that one from the array of keys:

```bash
jq -c 'keys - ["key_to_filter"]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JTYjz_vjkWJ)

More verbosely but also more efficiently (if it matters), you could use a `map` to `select` what you want:

```bash
jq -c 'keys | map(select(. != "key_to_filter"))'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iZ0-zgNK5xm)

As @artild pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230039/how-to-filter-a-key-using-jq-in-bash/75230082#comment132752059_75230082), you could also first `del`ete the item in question, and just then get all keys:

```bash
jq -c 'del(.key_to_filter) | keys'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/o2TMs7SqUFd)

Output:

```json
["a_key","c_key"]
```

Note that `keys` returns a sorted array. If you want them unsorted, use `keys_unsorted` instead.

Comment: Or you could delete key before `keys` function:

    `del(.key_to_filter) | keys`

Comment: Thank you @pmf @artild. If I have an array `("a_key" "key_to_filter")` - how to tell `jq` to filter all the keys in this array? For example, here I'll just get `c_key`

Comment: @YoniMelki Note that for an array you need to use brackets `[…]`, not parens `(…)`, and commas between the items. Using the first approach is straightforward, just subtract the array: `keys - ["a_key", "key_to_filter"]`; for the second you'd need a conjunction like `all` on the array items as in `keys | map(select(all(. != ["a_key", "key_to_filter"][]; .)))`; and with the third it's straightforward again, just iterate over the items and use them as indices: `del(.[["a_key", "key_to_filter"][]]) | keys`

Comment: Thanks for the response @pmf . But if I want to store those keys in a variable I need to declare them with `(...)`. How can I apply the entire variable (which is an array) to the jq filter?

Comment: @YoniMelki I have a growing suspicion that you are confusing Bash arrays with JSON/jq arrays. One way to import an indexed Bash array into jq is to use `--args "${arrayname[@]}"` as the last parameter when invoking jq, and `$ARGS.positional` to retrieve it inside jq.

Comment: @pmf I'm definitely confused since I didn't even know that there were a difference

Comment: Both your shell (where you type in commands and launch jq from) and jq (a CLI tool) are scripting environments, each with their own data structures and memory management. As for the shell, on Linux/Mac people typically use dash or bash or zsh, and PowerShell on Windows (try out `echo $SHELL`); most but not all of them support both indexed and associative arrays. jq on the other hand doesn't care what shell you use, it implements JSON arrays and JSON objects to store collections. Of course there are means to carry over data from one structure into another, but they are from two distinct worlds.